# Angular5: show hidden rows in ag-grid

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

Below is my service response, as soon as the page loads the grid shows only those rows whose `result` is `yes`. Now, my page also has a `show all` check box, so as soon as the checkbox is checked all the hidden rows should also be visible and as as soon as I un-check the check-box only rows with `result = yes` should be visible. How can I achieved this show/hide rows functionality? Please guide. Below is my code so far, I did used `refreshCells` but it is not giving me expected results.

```
    data = {
        name: "A",
        result: "no"
       },
       {
        name: "B",
        result: "no"
       },
       {
        name: "C",
        result: "yes"
       },
       {
        name: "D",
        result: "yes"
       }

    private gridApi;
    private dataCopy;

    constructor() {
      this.dataCopy = data;
    }

    this.gridOptions = {
      isExternalFilterPresent: function() { 
        return true; 
      },

      doesExternalFilterPass: function(rowNode) { 
        return rowNode.data.result = "yes"; 
      }
    };

    onGridReady(params) {
       this.gridApi = params.api;
    }

    //function call on checkbox click
    showAll(event) {
      if(event.target.checked) {
        this.gridApi.refreshCells(this.dataCopy); 
      }
    }

    //HTML
    <input type="checkbox" (change)=showAll($event)
```

Comment: Just saw this. Do you still need help with it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your use of ag-grid's `api.refreshCells()`, I don't think that will result in the grid in updating the row values, as the intended behaviour of that method will only affect the cells which are currently rendered, as mentioned in the [documentation](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-refresh/#view-refresh).

You can adopt the following ways which willallow you to [update row nodes](https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-grid-data-update/#bulk-updating) instead, and there are a few approaches when it comes to that.

1) With one-way data binding to the `[rowData]` input property binding. This will work for frameworks such as Angular and React. You can do this by binding your checkbox to a `change` event. Then, we create a shallow copy of your data, and then filter/assign your row data values according to the checkbox selection. I have made a short demo [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/zwg9xvTmhErfQ0PyvIPD?p=preview).

```
<input type="checkbox" (change)="toggleCheckbox($event)"/>
.
.

ngOnInit() {
  this.dataCopy = [...this.rowData];
}

toggleCheckbox(event){
  if (event.target.checked) {
    this.rowData = this.dataCopy;
  } else {
    this.rowData = this.dataCopy.filter(obj => obj.result === 'yes');
  }
}
```

2) Using `api.setRowData(newData)`.

3) Using `api.updateRowData(transaction)`. Using this method is preferred, if you want to maintain the previous grid state.

Comment: thank. I used the same code as in plunker but on checkbox check and un-check I am getting error as "ImmutableService requires getRowNodeId() callback to be implemented". Can you guide me on this.

Comment: @Anna Glad to help! Anyways, I would recommend you to use `api.updateRowData()`, instead of directly setting the row data, given there may be the use case whereby you might want to maintain the grid states, such as sorting and filtering.